# Display multiple datas from checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

How can I get multiple datas from checkboxes to another modal? If I click on a button, a bootstrap modal appears with some datas. The datas have checkboxes. And I want to print the selected datas on another modal in a table. I'm trying to push the value, but It's just prints the checkbox values and I want to print the `name` and the `connected to`.

### My code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#checkBtn2").click(function() {
            var favorite = [];
            $.each($("input[name='case']:checked"), function() {
                favorite.push($(this).val());
            });
            $('#myModal2').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                $("#checkid").html(favorite.join(", "));
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
        <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Connect to</th>
            <th>View</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Data1</td>
            <td>Data2</td>
            <td align="center"><input name="case" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="data1"</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>Data2</td>
            <td>Data3</td>
            <td align="center"><input name="case" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="data2"</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>Data3</td>
            <td></td>
            <td align="center"><input name="case" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="data3"</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>Data4</td>
            <td>Data5</td>
            <td align="center"><input name="case" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="data4"</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>Data5</td>
            <td>Data6</td>
            <td align="center"><input name="case" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="data5"</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>Data6</td>
            <td></td>
            <td align="center"><input name="case" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="data6"</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type='button' name='case' id='checkBtn2' value='View' class='btn btn-info'>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <p id="checkid"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so you want name and connectTo with checkbox value in modal.. right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#checkBtn2").click(function() {
    var favorite = [];
    $.each($("input[name='case']:checked"), function() {
      var elem = $(this);
      var parent = elem.parents("tr:first");
      var name = parent.find("td:first").text();
      var connectedTo = parent.find("td:eq(1)").text();
      favorite.push(name + ":" + connectedTo);
    });
    $('#myModal2').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      $("#checkid").html(favorite.join(", "));
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Connect to</th>
            <th>View</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Data1</td>
            <td>Data2</td>
            <td align="center"><input name="case" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="data1" </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

            <td>Data2</td>
            <td>Data3</td>
            <td align="center"><input name="case" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="data2" </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

            <td>Data3</td>
            <td></td>
            <td align="center"><input name="case" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="data3" </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

            <td>Data4</td>
            <td>Data5</td>
            <td align="center"><input name="case" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="data4" </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

            <td>Data5</td>
            <td>Data6</td>
            <td align="center"><input name="case" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="data5" </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>

            <td>Data6</td>
            <td></td>
            <td align="center"><input name="case" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="data6" </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type='button' name='case' id='checkBtn2' value='View' class='btn btn-info'>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p id="checkid"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue with your code is that input does not have the "connectedTo" data in the html. Either get it from the td elements or modify the html so that you can store the same data in the data attributes in the input.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can get the closest `tr` of the `checkbox checked` and feed it as `json object` to `favorite` variable. Then you can retrieve it within modal using `for-loop`. That will make it more organized.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#checkBtn2").click(function() {
            var favorite = [];
            $.each($("input[name='case']:checked"), function() {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var data1 = $(tr).find('td').eq(0).text();
                var data2 = $(tr).find('td').eq(1).text();
                var data = {data1: data1, data2: data2};
                favorite.push(data);
            });
            $('#myModal2').modal('show').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                $("#checkid").html("");
                for(var i=0;i < favorite.length; i++){
                  $("#checkid").append('<div>'+favorite[i].data1 +',' + favorite[i].data2 +'</div>');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        
        <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Connect to</th>
            <th>View</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Data1</td>
            <td>Data2</td>
            <td align="center"><input name="case" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="data1"</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>Data2</td>
            <td>Data3</td>
            <td align="center"><input name="case" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="data2"</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>Data3</td>
            <td></td>
            <td align="center"><input name="case" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="data3"</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>Data4</td>
            <td>Data5</td>
            <td align="center"><input name="case" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="data4"</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>Data5</td>
            <td>Data6</td>
            <td align="center"><input name="case" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="data5"</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            
            <td>Data6</td>
            <td></td>
            <td align="center"><input name="case" class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" value="data6"</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type='button' name='case' id='checkBtn2' value='View' class='btn btn-info'>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="basicModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <p id="checkid"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```